# KSH: Loop through a double quoted comma separated variable

Tags: loops, for-loop, escaping, ksh, double-quotes

Using KSH. I have a variable that contains strings enclosed in double quotes and separated by commas, I would like to loop through these strings, I do not want to recognise commas in the double quotes as separators.

I've tried setting IFS to IFS="\",\"" and IFS="," but it still recognises the comma inside the double quotes.

Simplified:

```
errorStrings="Some error","Another error","This, error"
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
for error in $errorStrings;do
  echo "Checking for $error"
  #grep "$error" file >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$error found"
  continue
done
IFS=$oldIFS


Actual:
Checking for Some error
Checking for Another error
Checking for This
Checking for  error

Expected:
Checking for Some error
Checking for Another error
Checking for This, error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that the `errorStrings` is not what you expect. Try

```
echo "e=[${errorStrings}]"
```

When you want the double quotes inside your string, use

```
errorStrings='"Some error","Another error","This, error"'
```

Your script will work better when you quote `$errorStrings` in the for-loop.

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
for error in "$errorStrings";do
  echo "Checking for $error"
  #grep "$error" file >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$error found"
  continue
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

This loop still has to be modified for deleting the quotes.
Perhaps this is a good moment for using an array:

```
errorStrings=("Some error" "Another error" "This, error")
for error in "${errorStrings[@]}";do
  echo "Checking for $error"
  #grep "$error" file >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$error found"
  continue
done
```

I am not sure what options you have in your environment, perhaps this will work too:

```
errorStrings='"Some error","Another error","This, error"'

echo "${errorStrings}" | sed 's/","/"\n"/g' | while read error; do
   echo "Checking for $error"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @walter-a (how do I quote your id?). Quoting $errorStrings as "$errorStrings" just made the shell treat it as one long single string. I decided to use sed as you suggested.  errorStrings is pulled in from a config file that env users can set error strings to check for in logs. I used: sed 's/^\"//;s/\"$//;s/\",\"/\\n/g' in the assignment of errorStrings.

Comment: @AndyW I think you quote without the space, just like I did now with `Andy W`